# How to change file directory after build?

Tags: html, webpack, configuration

How to move my index.html file to 'dist' folder after build? Before npm install and npm run build folder 'dist' s not located in my project it appears after first build and after that I'd like to move automatically my index.html file to this location.

I was searching information on the Internet, found only two thing that attatched to my eyes.
One was "html webpack plugin" but it only creates a new empty index.html folder after build
Second, I found some plug in on github that theoretically can move file to choosen directory but I not working

Answer (score 0):

You can just issue a `cp` command at runtime.  Inside your `package.json` file, in the `scripts` section, add an additional command. IE

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "react-scripts build && cp build/index.html ../dist/index.html",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Should I instal some thing at first? Becaue when I insert this line to my package.json an write in terminal "npm run build" it shows this comment:
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: And also I had build line in package.json and when I entered you line, everything goes red underline. Should I rename one of this builds or just extend the text after the colon

Comment: This is just my build command ..  You can only have 1.   ADD `&& cp build/index.html ../dist/index.html` to the end of YOUR build command inside the quotes ..